# Cascading drop down list with Angular 2 using Promise

Tags: angular

I have two select drop down lists. The first one lists domains and the second one categories belonging to a domain.  When I am selecting a domain, the id of the domain is sent.  The API is provided by a Laravel generated json. If there is a match in the categories object than those matches should be returned (if sent id equals activity_domain_id) .

Select method from the app component

```
seleDomain(domainId: number) {
                this.formsService.getDomains()
                .then(categories => this.categories.filter(item => item.activity_domain_id === domainId))
                .catch(error => this.error = error);
        }
```

This is how the Categories and Domain classes look like:

```
export class Domain {
    id: number;
    user_id: number;
    name: string;
}

export class Categories {
  id: number;
  activity_domain_id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

get domains and get categories methods from the service component

```
  getDomains(domain: Domain): Promise<Domain[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.domainsUrl)
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  getCategories(userId: number): Promise<Categories[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl)
            .toPromise()
            .then(this.extractData)
            .catch(this.handleError);
  }

 private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || { };
 }
```

Here is how the domains json returned by extractData  looks like:

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":1,"name":"I.T","updated_at":"2016-10-06 14:07:55","created_at":"2016-03-03 19:28:54"},{"id":3,"user_id":1,"name":"Management","updated_at":"2016-10-06 16:27:18","created_at":"2016-08-09 15:10:34"}]
```

Here is how the categories json returned by extractData looks like:

```
[{"id":9,"activity_domain_id":1,"name":"Front end developer","updated_at":"2016-09-06 10:19:23","created_at":"2016-09-05 15:21:08"},{"id":10,"activity_domain_id":1,"name":"Back end developer","updated_at":"2016-09-05 15:21:20","created_at":"2016-09-05 15:21:20"}]
```

No match returns when I do the filter.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Why do you call getDomains() (which, according to its name, should return several domains), when the user selects a single domain ID. Why do you call it without any argument, although the method in the service expects an argument of type Domain? Why does this method, however, ignore its argument? You really need to choose good names from your methods, specify meaninful arguments, and document the methods. Documenting them will force you to think about what they're supposed to do.

Comment: getDomains() returns all the domains that are listed in the first drop down from where the user can chose only one. I am calling it without any argument because I need all the values for the first drop down where all the domains are listed